# Is there a way to expose and call function defined in LLVM IR into Clang C++?

Tags: c++, llvm, ffi

I would like to define a function in LLVM IR and somehow expose it into Clang so I can call it from C++. Is there a way to do this?

For example, in LLVM IR:

```
declare { i64, i64 } @divrem(i64, i64)
```

And then in C++:

```
struct ret { long div, rem; };
extern "LLVM IR" ret divrem(long, long);

...

auto dr = divrem(30, 11);
```

Or whatever mapping of the LLVM IR function to a C++ function makes the most sense.

Comment: It's probably just `extern "C"` from the C++ side, and invoke LLVM to generate the `.o` file

Comment: `extern "C"` works as long as the LLVM IR function has a normal C/C++ ABI.

Comment: Note that `long` is a 32-bit integer on some 64-bit platforms (notably Windows) and virtually all 32-bit platforms. So it's safer to use `long long` or, even better, `int64_t`.